# Smart rooting in Sinatra app on Apache2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, apache, sinatra

On my local Apache2 I have multiple applications. My httpd.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/

  RackBaseURI /app1
  RackBaseURI /app2
  RackBaseURI /app3
</VirtualHost>
```

config.ru of every application looks the same:

```
require './app'
root_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
set :environment, ENV['RACK_ENV'].to_sym
set :root, root_dir
set :app_file, File.join(root_dir, 'app.rb')
disable :run
run Sinatra::Application
```

In /var/www/ directory I have symbolic links to public folder of each of my applications. (app1/public  -->  the link called app1,   app2/public  -->  the link called app2, etc)

If I open localhost/app1 is starts action  (get '/' of app1)

```
get '/' do
  erb :main
end
```

So far so good, everything works. In the view main.erb  ( loaded in  get '/' aciton) I'm loading some javascripts from public/js directory.

And here appears my problem. I have to load them like that (focus on src="/app1/....."):

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/app1/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

While I'd like to load them like that:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

The reason is that when I upload my application on e.q. Heorku it doesn't work anymore until I remove every "/app1" from my code.

To sum up, on localhost my Sinatra app1 takes localhost/ as root though the real root should be localhost/app1/. On the other hand on heroku it takes app1.heroku.com/ as root which is ok.

So the question is what can I do to make each of my applications take localhost/appX/ as a root?

Edit:

This problem also involves javascripts:   (/**app1**/some_action)
On localhost it has to be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#a_button").click(function(){
    $("#some_div").load("/app1/some_action");
  });
});
```

While on a server it has to be be like that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#a_button").click(function(){
    $("#some_div").load("/some_action");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create helper method that will prepend appropriate prefix to your URLs depending on the environment, or use [static assets](https://github.com/wbzyl/sinatra-static-assets/) sinatra helper.

Comment: It solves only half of my problems. It doesn't fix javascripts - details added to the question.